# Should Core Data Stack inherit from NSObject and why?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Recently it is practice to move the core data stack implementation from the app delegate to a different class. In most implementations I see that the core data stack inherits from NSObject, even in Apple's documentation.

1. Is there a reason for that? It seems to work without it.
2. Why is Apple's init method not calling super.init() isn't it a must have?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init() {
        // This resource is the same name as your xcdatamodeld contained in your project.
        guard let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("DataModel", withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom)
        managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
            let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
            let docURL = urls[urls.endIndex-1]
            /* The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file.
             This code uses a file named "DataModel.sqlite" in the application's documents directory.
             */
            let storeURL = docURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
            do {
                try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
            } catch {
                fatalError("Error migrating store: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Initializing the Core Data Stack](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1)

Comment: "it is practice to move the core data stack implementation from the app delegate to a different class" whose practice? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, I added Apple's code sample of their CDS aka DataController

Comment: Is that what the project templates look like too? Do they use a DataController object distinct from the AppDelegate?

Comment: Which project do you mean?

Comment: Any of the Core Data templates when you make a new project.

Comment: No, there isn't a DataController at all. CDS is combined with the AppDelegate. Maybe the project template isn't updated in Xcode 7.3 yet, maybe after the wwdc.

Answer (score 2):

The stack can live in any object in theory, and in Swift that object need not derive from NSObject. But in reality it also needs to be a singleton globally available to all code, and the demands of Occam's Razor and time will always make the app delegate an obvious locus, since it meets that description perfectly, and especially if that's where it is when you make a new project from the Core Data templates.

> Why is Apple's init method not calling super.init() isn't it a must have?

It is done automatically by Swift itself.

Comment: But I encourage you to implement singleton and do this properly. And when you do, there's no need to derive from NSObject in Swift.

Comment: "It is done automatically by Swift itself." How do you know that?

Comment: I can see it happening, using symbolic breakpoints. Also it is well documented here. Plus I was directly told by someone at Apple. I have a bug filed against it, as I do not like secret behavior of this kind.